# Apply MS Project SetTaskMode via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I am reading a sheet in Excel and creating a Microsoft Project Plan of tasks, Work, Notes, etc.

The code is being executed out of MS Excel.

How can I get the `Active.Project` to assign, `SetTaskMode Manual:= False`?

I receive an error, please note `Application.Visible = True`.

As far as `.Application.Methods` (Project) go, I am able to invoke the `Application.About` screen, i.e  on Sub execution the MS Project About screen opens up, however after that line, it stops.

Basically, I would like to set the Active Sheet Task Mode to be set to 'automatically scheduled' as the default for all tasks as they are being imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project property in question is [NewTasksCreatedAsManual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.newtaskscreatedasmanual) and is used like this to make all new tasks auto-scheduled:

```
ActiveProject.NewTasksCreatedAsManual = False
```

Alternatively, to set the task mode to auto-schedule on an individual task, use the [Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.manual) property like this:

```
tsk.Manual = False
    
' or to change to manually scheduled
tsk.Manual = True
```

Comment: Dear Rachel, 

I have applied ActiveProject.NewTasksCreatedAsManual = False and it has worked. Thank you so very much. My Tasks are now being imported as Automatically Scheduled..